# What is the actual status of CiviHR

Tags: extension, civihr

Is CiviHR still active? This extension looks really interesting but the last release is almost 3 years-old.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, they had too many issues with the more recent versions of CiviCRM so it's no longer supported.  A client of mine had a chat with Jamie @ Compucorp last February (2020) at the CiviCamp and the message I got from my client is that they were no longer supporting it. I don't know the details so you'd need to speak to Compucorp for more info

Comment: Thanks Rose for this information.

Comment: That's sad - a lot of investment went into CiviHR.

Comment: very sad! I was just looking at it today

Comment: @Zachery my client did go on to use CiviCRM for their HR system but we had to build it from the ground up and plan out our own processes. It is certainly inspired by CiviHR but has less ‘hard-coded’ customisation and relies a lot on Drupal Views and webforms.

Comment: @RoseLanigan we have a non-profit client who is interested in CiviHR functionality. Would you be able to share your configuration?

Comment: @Darren I've only just seen your message, apoloigies for the (very!) late reply. If it would be useful, I'm happy to discuss but it's fairly bespoke and a bit too detailed for a comment here. You could email me via Ruza Solutions.