# want to get more details about CiviHR

Tags: civihr

we plan to make use of CiviCRM to capture the vacation and leave of staff, can we do that or someone has tried this? I heard there is CiviHR available, can someone tell us where we can get more details about this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So far as I know, CiviHR was abandoned.  See [What is the actual status of CiviHR](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/40171/what-is-the-actual-status-of-civihr)

It used to have a website at civihr.org but that timed out when I tried it just now.

Comment: Thanks for the details